# HTML5 Video Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am confuse on how to use html5 video tags with rails. I few questions

1- What is a source file .ogg?? Can't I just use a mp4 file and insert it in my video tags.

2- If i want to show video/image to all member it should be in public? Then how do i access public, and how do i access video in a different folder such as assert/video if i create it.

3- I have the following file but doesn't show anything any file any reason why?

4- Do i need to code it to encode the video first? or just insert it into a file. Is ogg a good encoder or zencoder better?

Javascript (application.js)

```
function init() {
            if( !document.createElement('video').canPlayType ) return;
            var videos = document.querySelectorAll( 'div.video' ),
                videosLength = videos.length;
            for( var i=0; i < videosLength; i++ ) {
                var root = videos[i];
                    video = root.querySelector( 'video' ),
                    play = document.createElement( 'button' ),
                    mute = document.createElement( 'button' );
                video.controls = false;
                // Initial class name
                play.className = 'video-button video-play';
                play.innerHTML = play.title = 'Play';
                play.onclick = function() {
                    if( video.paused ) {
                        video.play();
                        // Additional class names for container and button while playing
                        root.className += ' video-on';
                        play.className += ' video-play-on';
                        play.innerHTML = play.title = 'Pause';
                    } else {
                        video.pause();
                        // Remove additional class names for container and button in paused state
                        root.className = root.className.replace( ' video-on', '' );
                        play.className = play.className.replace( ' video-play-on', '' );
                        play.innerHTML = play.title = 'Play';
                    }
                }
                // Initial class name
                mute.className = 'video-button video-mute';
                mute.innerHTML = mute.title = 'Mute';
                mute.onclick = function() {
                    if( video.muted ) {
                        video.muted = false;
                        // Remove additional class name in unmuted state
                        mute.className = mute.className.replace( ' video-mute-on', '' );
                        mute.innerHTML = mute.title = 'Mute';
                    } else {
                        video.muted = true;
                        // Additional class name for button in muted state
                        mute.className += ' video-mute-on';
                        mute.innerHTML = mute.title = 'Unmute';
                    }
                }
                root.appendChild( play );
                root.appendChild( mute );
            }
        }
        window.onload = init;
```

HTML (index.html.erb)

```
<video controls poster="video/video.jpg" width="854" height="480">
    <source src="m/video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="video/trailer_test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="m/player.swf" width="854" height="504">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=video.mp4">
    <!--[if IE]><!--><param name="movie" value="m/player.swf"><!--<![endif]-->
    <img src="m/video.jpg" width="854" height="480" alt="Video">
    <p>Your browser can&rsquo;t play HTML5 video. <a href="m/video.ogv"> Download it</a> instead.</p>
    </object>
</video>
```

CSS (application.css)

```
body {
            margin:0;
            padding:50px;
            background:#444;
            }

        /* Video */
        .video {
            position:relative;
            overflow:hidden;
            float:left;
            background:#000;
            color:#fff;
            }
            .video video {
                display:block;
                opacity:.4;
                -webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
                -moz-transition:all .2s linear;
                -o-transition:all .2s linear;
                transition:all .2s linear;
                }
            .video:hover video {
                opacity:.6;
                }
        .video-on video,
        .video-on:hover video {
            opacity:1;
            }

        /* Button */
        .video-button {
            position:absolute;
            z-index:1;
            border:none;
            background:#CCC;
            text-indent:-9999px;
            cursor:pointer;
            -webkit-transform:scale(1.0);
            -moz-transform:scale(1.0);
            -o-transform:scale(1.0);
            transform:scale(1.0);
            -webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
            -moz-transition:all .2s linear;
            -o-transition:all .2s linear;
            transition:all .2s linear;
            }
        .video-button:hover {
            -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
            -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
            -o-transform:scale(1.1);
            transform:scale(1.1);
            }
        .video-button:after {
            position:absolute;
            background:url(i/buttons.png) no-repeat;
            content:'';
            }

        /* Play */
        .video-play {
            bottom:30px;
            left:30px;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 50px #FFF,
                inset 5px 5px 20px #444,
                inset 0 -20px 40px #000;
            -moz-box-shadow:0 0 50px #FFF,
                inset 5px 5px 20px #444,
                inset 0 -20px 40px #000;
            box-shadow:0 0 50px #FFF,
                inset 5px 5px 20px #444,
                inset 0 -20px 40px #000;
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
            -webkit-border-radius:25px;
            -moz-border-radius:25px;
            border-radius:25px;
            }
        .video-play:after {
            top:15px;
            left:16px;
            width:21px;
            height:21px;
            background-position:0 0;
            }
        .video-play-on:after {
            background-position:-23px 0;
            }

        /* Mute */
        .video-mute {
            bottom:35px;
            left:100px;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 30px #FFF,
                inset 4px 4px 15px #444,
                inset 0 -15px 35px #000;
            -moz-box-shadow:0 0 30px #FFF,
                inset 4px 4px 15px #444,
                inset 0 -15px 35px #000;
            box-shadow:0 0 30px #FFF,
                inset 4px 4px 15px #444,
                inset 0 -15px 35px #000;
            width:38px;
            height:38px;
            -webkit-border-radius:19px;
            -moz-border-radius:19px;
            border-radius:19px;
            }
        .video-mute:after {
            top:13px;
            left:11px;
            width:17px;
            height:14px;
            background-position:0 -21px;
            }
        .video-mute-on:after {
            background-position:-18px -21px;
            }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**> 1- What is a source file .ogg?? Can't I just use a mp4 file and insert it in my video tags.**
Yes you can just use mp4. See the Rails API on video_tag. It works with mp4. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-video_tag

**> 2- If i want to show video/image to all member it should be in public? Then how do i access public, and how do i access video in a different folder such as assert/video if i create it.**
An easy way to do this is to use the paperclip gem for handling the video uploads. Very easy to grab the url you need to play it.

**> 3- I have the following file but doesn't show anything any file any reason why? > 4- Do i need to code it** 
If you are using mp4 in HTML5, you just need the video_tag, you don't need any of this

Comment: Thanks i don't like using gem i think it make ruby to complex, unless i see the gem file class in my own server location, which i haven't found yet (new to rails), I am force to use paperclip or can i use my own? Also do i need zencoder.

Comment: paperclip is a very popular gem will make your life easier in general. If you are using mp4 files you don't need zencoder for them to play in html5 video_tag tags

Comment: At the moment i am using mp4, but it will be uploaded by many users, and different type, so i should use zencoder to allow different file to be converted into one type? The reason i don't like gem to much his they fetch the information from an external source and not sure if they are subject to change, which may compromise my app (not sure but it feel that way)